# Whether to go for React responsive web app vs PWA?

Tags: reactjs, web, responsive-design, architecture, progressive-web-apps

We have a college management system developed over a decade as and when requirements came along. The project team comprised of students currently doing graduation in the course. These students are paid extra for work and are allowed one extra year to complete their graduation. The project also has two dedicated (non-student) developers who manage smooth transition of system from one outgoing / graduating student team to incoming / admitting student team. The development initially started up in Java. But due to student's unfamiliarity with Java tech stack and ad hoc requirement's strict deadlines, they resorted to use the technology of their choice, sometimes Java, sometimes PHP. Also, over the period of time, the whole system has grown unmanageable due to lack of pre-thought design. So, we decided to streamline things a bit. Some years back we tried to reimplement everything in ERP. But after an year of efforts, ERP implementers were not able to deliver the satisfiable customization. So, now, we are thinking of rebuilding the whole system with proper design, with single tech stack. Since major code is in Java, we are thinking to reuse Java server side code and rewrite the rest of server side code in other languages in Java. So we are remained with decision of client side.

We have to take decision how correct it is **in today's mobile era** to be content with just browser only web app and not have any plan of mobile app, especially if there is not much difference in efforts involved in developed in the two (because we dont want to hamper student's course work). (We use msteams, webex for online lectures and collaboration, moodle for grading and other coursework. All have corresponding apps. And also another app for carrying exams.) I guess developing and maintaining native app is a lot of efforts. So in cross-platform area, we are left with progressive web apps, which I feel really dont involve far too much extra effort over responsive web app, but not sure.

So here are my questions:

**Q1.** How much is the difference in efforts involved in developing and maintaining React web app vs React PWA? (as we are thinking to go for React for our client side app)

**Q2.** How much code is shared by react web app and react PWA, if we want to have both web app and pwa? and hence will it involve substantial extra effort to develop and maintain both with exactly same functionality?

**Q3.** Can we achieve everything with react PWA that we can with web app can?

**Q4.** If we can develop and maintain both react web app and pwa with not much extra efforts (as asked in Q2), is proceeding with developing both makes logical sense given the information I gave in first two paragraphs? Or more precisely, we can start up with react web app and as time permits, we can work on turning it up in pwa (which will be very much possible?) and then maintain both?

Comment: A quick decision filter: If you want your app to be installed (like Android / iOS native apps) in the user's mobile devices, go with PWA.

Answer (score 0):

A PWA is just a web app that follows all of the best practices for building web apps.

If you build a React Web App that meets the [installability criteria](https://web.dev/install-criteria/), it's a Progressive Web App. To meet the installability criteria, you'd need to add a service worker to provide some level of [offline experience](https://web.dev/offline-fallback-page/), and a [web app manifest](https://web.dev/add-manifest/).

Because a PWA is just a web app, there is only one code base, and there's nothing extra to maintain. It's a web app, so it can do everything a web app can do.